# Getting Error: Could not find or load main class while opening executable Jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm opening `fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar`

Using `java -jar /home/ubuntu/Downloads/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar` but getting error

```
Could not find or load main class
```

Also tried :

```
 java -cp /home/ubuntu/Downloads/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-1.3.0/lib/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-1.3.0.jar de.jensd.fx.glyphs.browser.GlyphsBrowser
```

and getting:
`Error: Could not find or load main class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.browser.GlyphsBrowser
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/layout/VBox`

Another try:

```
java -jar fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.browser.GlyphsBrowserApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

> JavaFX is no longer packaged with JDK but I think it is from JDK 11 and I'm using JDK 8 so why I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`
>   I'm using `open-jdk 8.0`

So how to do?

Comment: javafx is a separate download, you might need to look for the correct package to install

Comment: @Hitobat It is not about JavaFX installation.

Comment: @Hemlata it is about javafx, apparently: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/layout/VBox`

Comment: @h0r53 I tried but it is not working.

Comment: @khachik But I was able to open that jar when I was using ubuntu recently I switched to KDE Neon and I'm not able to open jars. Even I'm getting same error for other jars while opening them.

Comment: @khachik you can see my errors that all are giving different classpath while I'm using -cp and without -cp gives differ paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'main class not found' error comes in 2 cases:

1. Manifest.MF file of the .jar package does not contain a valid 'Main-Class' attribute. This can happen due to the .jar file not being created correctly. This is mostly a bug with the creation of jar file.
2. The Jar file is meant to be used as a library, but not as an executable program and therefore, it does not contain any class with 'main' method.

For case # 1 (bug in manifest.mf), these are the possible workarounds / fixes:

1. Ask the provider of jar file to create it again with proper 'Main-Class' definition in the manifest.mf file
2. Extract the contents of jar file to a directory, add 'Main-Class' attribute to manifest.mf file and package the folder into jar again.

Here is an article from Oracle on how the manifest.mf file can be updated:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix this problem by using **Oracle** JDK **8**.